# How to get command result out of minecraft server screen session?

Tags: minecraft, gnu-screen

I'm running a minecraft server inside a screen session. I want to send a command to that screen session and get the command result back (and print it back). Can I do that without using the `screen -L` option?

Demonstration inside of a bash script (obviously wrong!):

```
result=$(screen -S "minecraft-server" -p 0 -X stuff "list"`echo -ne '\015'`)
printf "$result\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the logs. Everything printed to screen is also printed to log:

My minecraft server is located at /home/minecraft, and runs as the 'minecraft' user (not me).

1. Send message:

   `screen -p 0 -S minecraft-server -X eval 'stuff "say TEST MESSAGE..."\\015'`
2. Read the output several ways:

   - `tail /home/minecraft/logs/latest.log`
   - `less /home/minecraft/logs/latest.log` plus CTRL+G to advance to the end
   - `less /home/minecraft/logs/latest.log` plus CTRL+F to keep monitoring new output as it arrives.